# how to restore multiline command using mysql?

Tags: mysql, cmd

[image: this picture shows my multiline command]

Now i figured out there is a problem with my command so if i hit the up arrow to get the last command i get two separate command, so i have to type it again. 
Please help i want to use command line but also not want to retype the same command again.

[this is the first line of my code when i hit the up arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dALXg.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean you get two separate commands?

Comment: if i hit the up arrow key for the first time i get "'f', '1993-02-04');" and if i hit it for the second time i get this "insert into pets values ('Fluffy', 'Harold', 'cat',"

Comment: I only want to get the full command, i do not want to type it again for each typo i made.  Do you understand me?

Comment: That is funky. I'm unable to replicate https://imgur.com/a/CXZhcpb When I hit the up arrow it brings up the full previous line (even though I had a line break).

Comment: what is the operating system you use?

Comment: That's on Ubuntu 16.04 through SSH using Termius on Windows 10.

Comment: I wonder if [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813051/command-history-in-mysql-client-only-showing-last-line-of-multiline-query) would help.

Comment: No it does Not work.